# Importing React component with Redux methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I put together a simple component to try and get my head around some React and Redux concepts.

I'm now trying to seperate the Redux logic into a seperate component, so that there's two components in total.

When I try to compile, all the methods/objects in `NewComponent` are undefined. When I add context with `this` I get the same errors.

Below is my original component (which works fine) before trying to put the Redux methods/objects in to a seperate component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'


const incrementAction = {
  type: 'INCREMENT',
  value: 1
}

const decrementAction = {
  type: 'DECREMENT',
  value: 1
}

function reducer(state = 0, action) {
  if (action.type === 'INCREMENT') {
    return state + 1
  } else if (action.type === 'DECREMENT'){
    return state - 1
  } else {
    return state
  }
}

// Map Redux state to component props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    value: state
  }
}

// Map Redux actions to component props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onIncrementClick: () => dispatch(incrementAction),
    onDecrementClick: () => dispatch(decrementAction)
  }
}


const store = createStore(reducer)



class View extends Component {

  showState() {
      console.log(store.getState())
  }


  render() {

    const { value, onIncrementClick, onDecrementClick } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title"></h1>
        </header>

      <h2>Counter</h2>

      <div onClick = {onIncrementClick}> <p className="button"> + </p></div>
      <div onClick = {onDecrementClick}> <p className="button"> - </p></div>
      <div onClick = {this.showState}> <p className="button"> Show State </p></div>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

View = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(View)


const WrappedApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <View />
  </Provider>
);

export default WrappedApp;
```

**EDIT**

Here are the components after I tried to break up the above.

`NewComponent`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'


class NewComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    const incrementAction = {
      type: 'INCREMENT',
      value: 1
    }

    const decrementAction = {
      type: 'DECREMENT',
      value: 1
    }

    const store = createStore(reducer)

  }



  reducer(state = 0, action) {
    if (action.type === 'INCREMENT') {
      return state + 1
    } else if (action.type === 'DECREMENT'){
      return state - 1
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }

  // Map Redux state to component props
  mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      value: state
    }
  }

  // Map Redux actions to component props
  mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      onIncrementClick: () => dispatch(incrementAction),
      onDecrementClick: () => dispatch(decrementAction)
    }
  }

}


export default NewComponent;
```

And `View`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import NewComponent from './NewComponent'


class View extends Component {

  showState() {
      console.log(this.store.getState())
  }

  render() {

    const { value, onIncrementClick, onDecrementClick } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title"></h1>
        </header>

      <h2>Counter</h2>

      <div onClick = {onIncrementClick}> <p className="button"> + </p></div>
      <div onClick = {onDecrementClick}> <p className="button"> - </p></div>
      <div onClick = {this.showState}> <p className="button"> Show State </p></div>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

View = connect(
  this.mapStateToProps,
  this.mapDispatchToProps
)(View)

const WrappedApp = () => (
  <Provider store={this.store}>
    <View />
  </Provider>
);

export default WrappedApp;
```

I'm now getting:

`Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(View)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(View)".`

Comment: Could you show your code with your actual `NewComponent` as well? Right now it's hard to see what you've separated between that and your `View` component, and how they fit together.

Comment: @MartinWedvich Updated. Hopefully it's a little clearer.

Comment: Please post the updated code in the first file

Comment: @Rahamin added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have a technical background in OOP languages, right ? :)

A React `Component` is basically a function responsible of rendering something on the screen. 
If you want to organize your Redux related code, you don't have to wrap it in a React `Component`. Simply declare the functions and objects you need in separate files and use [JavaScript module import/export feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

You can then follow the [guidelines from Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics) on how to organize your Redux code.

For example, for your Redux store, you can end up with a `store.js` file which contains something like

```
...
export const store = createStore(reducer);
...
```

And then use it where you want by simply importing it

```
import store from 'store.js'
```

Comment: Ah perfect, got it working now. This is now quite obvious now that you mention it, given what React actually is. I mostly come from a Python background and i've only played around a bit with Ionic in the past, which seemed to need everything wrapped in components (though I could be wrong on this).

Answer (score -1):

You are not supposed to define the store twice as you do after splitting the code into two files. And you define a component that is not a real component. And these are only two things that are not great...

I don't think a good way to start building a react/redux project is by fixing the above code. A better way, that will serve you in the future, is the following:

1. First, download a basic redux code example. One that I recommend is [ReduxSimpleStarter](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter/blob/master/src/index.js). It is a good example of how to organize your folder tree in a redux project.
2. Once you have reviewed the above example, create a new project using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), run it, then start modifying it based on the redux example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by defining `store` twice - I haven't. If you mean that some of the imports at the top are redundant, I *know* this, which is why I didn't want to paste all the code in different files as I put it together hastily just to test out concepts. I knew nothing here is best practice. The original component that I wrote also worked, it only retuned errors after I tried to split it into different components. So it doesn't have 400 mistakes like you seem to be implying, and Arnauds simple advice below fixed it. Didn't need advice on file structures, I was just testing concepts.

Comment: Fine. sorry if I insulted you, didn't mean it, meant to help. My sincere apologies.